# issues running `npx react-native init <NAME>

Tags: node.js, react-native, homebrew, npx

I recently wiped my harddrive and upgraded my MacOS to Catalina. Now running on zsh for the first time. I installed Homebrew and then node v12.14.1, which I can confirm when I run `node --version`. When I try to initialize a React-Native app with `npx react-native init`, I get the following error:

`Command failed: '/usr/local/Cellar/node@12/12.14.1_1/bin/node' '/usr/local/Cellar/node@12/12.14.1_1/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js' config get cache --parseable`

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I was successfully able to run `npx react-native init <PROJECT>` by uninstalling and reinstalling Node with `nvm` instead of `brew`. Apparently installing with `nvm` allows for greater flexibility.

Comment: thank you it works. I uninstalled the node and npm. Then I install the nvm and using nvm I install the node. It works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Start from the top and make sure you’ve installed all the necessary components https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started